# Salir de sesión automaticamente cuando expira la sesion Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, sesiones

En el archivo de configuración de `session.php` tengo

```
'lifetime' => 1,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

Un minuto se vence la sesión y `expire_on_close` debe de salirse de sesión. Sin embargo no me funciona no sale de sesión. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando la sesión del usuario termine, Laravel se salga de sesión automáticamente?
Para el manejo de sesiones uso el `Auth` de `Laravel`.

Comment: No me queda claro lo que quieres lograr `que laravel salga de sesión`, ¿puedes dar un ejemplo más puntual?

Comment: cada pagina tiene permisos donde solo deja entrar al usuario si esta autenticado. Pero se estan presentando problemas porque cuando la sesion se vence aparece error 403. Hay usuarios que se confunden con este mensaje de error, entonces la idea es que por medio de laravel se haga un log out automaticamente cuando la sesion expire para facilitar  mas al usuario las cosas y evitar que hallan confusiones

Comment: Cuando vence la sesion el sistema de autenticación de laravel generalmente redirecciona automaticamente a login, quizá el problema no esté con la sesion.   
`expire_on_close` tengo entendido que cierra la sesion al cerrar el navegador, osea que eso no te deberia generar un error.    
Pienso que quizá el problema esté en algún middleware.   
¿Probaste en una instalación limpia de Laravel hacer `php artisan make:auth` y modificar el `lifetime`? Si la sesion esta activa podes entrar a `url/home` y si la sesion esta vencida al refrescar el navegador debería de redireccionarte a `url/login`

Comment: if ( !Auth::check() ) {
    return redirect('login');
}

Answer (score 0):

Si la opción `expire_on_close` tiene un valor `true`, el valor de espiración es 'session', esto quiere decir que la sesión expirará es al momento de cerrar el navegador, en otras palabras, ignora el valor de `lifetime`.

Si `expire_on_close` tiene un valor de `false`, entonces la sesión expirará en el valor de `lifetime`

He probado con `'expire_on_close' => true` y el valor de expiración del cookie `laravel_session` es `"Session"`, por lo que no toma el tiempo asignado en `lifetime`

Dejo una imagen con el valor de dicha cookie con el valor del tiempo de espiración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]